Measure for distribution uniformity
Is there some measure and a way to calculate it to distinguish between the values distributed evenly over the range and distributed with many spikes (of their amounts)?
For example, to distinguish sequences like:
Example 1: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2

with
Example 2: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 

and
Example 3: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2

I am looking for a metrics which will have something close to 0 when the value (let’s say 2 here) is evenly distributed over the sequence and close to 1 when all such values collected in one place; when I have localized groups like in example 2 I would like to have something close to 0.5 and in the example 3 something close to 0.7. The values are just to explain the logic, of course, they are approximate.
For example, if the question would be about one spike, I would use mean value and variance. But with many spikes this becomes different.
Does such a metrics (or similar) exists?
Some background on the context
I want a measure which will say if a specific lexem in text (represented by number) distributed evenly (like pronouns) or this is a term (like "permutation") which will tend to bulk to math books in large text base.
Update
For future research. The Interquartile range(IQR) could be of help here.

Should the measure take into account the order of the points, as taking it as a time series?

@kjetilbhalvorsen, just to be on the same page, "order" sounds tricky for me here because of "dual usage" (as I see it) here. The items have their own order and its key to speak about distribution in terms of collocation. On the other hand, they have internal order (second 1 follows first 1 in the example 3) and I am not concerned in the order. Again, we have order in terms 1, 2, etc. So, could you please specify which order do you mean exactly? My point of interest is to see of particular values are bulked or distributed evenly.

ok, formulate it differently: Would the uniformity measure you want be the same for any permutation?

@kjetilbhalvorsen, do you mean permutation of the same values (like two values of 1 are swapped) or you mean another kind of permutation? Just to be more specific about my background needs let me make a step aside of pure math wording I tried to figure out here. I want a measure which will say if a specific lexem in text (represented by number) distributed evenly (like pronouns) or this is a term (like "permutation") which will tend to bulk to math books in large text base. I will be thankful for any help if you see how to improve my question's wording.

Then please edit your post to explain your real applied context!

@kjetilbhalvorsen, would it help in any way, actually? I am generalizing to solve some math problem without specific applied context that could change. If my approach doesn't help and counterproductive, could you please explain why? My idea that less details is better, perfectness is achieved when nothing could be removed, not when anything else could be added, isn't it?

I think it could help, it often helps to get useful answers! I dont really understand your explanations, that might be just me, of course ... there are similar questions on site, a stored search

@kjetilbhalvorsen, I've updated the question. Can you please help now? I am reading the questions in the search (as well as the linked ones added when the question was closed), but I am not sure they applicable in may case. I would be thankful for anything more specific.

I also don’t fully understand what you are after, but it seems like TF-IDF can be useful for your purposes. This does require that you have different documents in which you can count occurrences of terms, though. It is also not scaled as required, but you could change the scale.

@Thom, thank you so much for the input. TF-IDF very close thing, but it compares the document frequency to overall term frequency. It starts with my end point. It assumes that I know the part of text of interests (document) and now I just need to see the TF-IDF ratio. My problem is that I don't have "documents", I have a huge text as a bulk and I don't know if there are spikes of density of terms in areas. My question could be worded as "should I start TF-IDF" search bulking text in "documents" or for this lexem no need for it at all, since it distributed evenly.

@Thom, this should work like I get some measure, get the value higher than a threshold (let's say 0.67) and after that my next question would be "show me bulks where these lexems occurs most often". But this next step I will do separately and this is another question. The first question if the specific lexem worth of further analysis.

Then I don’t know any formal procedure that is applicable. Something that’s seems intuitive to me is to calculate the average distance between any two occurrences of the same term (i.e., the average number of terms in-between the two) and compare these with some baseline (e.g., the length of your corpus over te number of occurrences of each term)? I guess someone else has better advice on this.
